# Recover truecrypt volume

Tags: data-recovery, truecrypt

I have a truecrypt volume saved as a file on a disk that windows one day decided to overwrite the NTFS index on. Some files was lost while others remain. In the case of the truecrypt volume it still exists but as a zero-byte file. I have not been writing any data to the disk since so there is chance of the volume still being there. How can i recover it?

I have tried various data recovery programs that were able to recover many other files but because the index is corrupt they need to know the format of the files in order to find them on the disk and I have not found any programs that supports truecrypt volumes.

Basically what needs to be done is to find the actual data on the disk and copy it. Perhaps the current zero-byte file points to the start of the file which could help. In any case I need some suggestions on how to successfully extract the data.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you are pretty much SOL with this one. These encryption types encrypt the data into unreadable format, so in the event of data loss it can never again be read by any data recovery software. I think the only solution in this case would be for the developer of truecrypt to develop their own data recovery software specifically designed to work with truecrypt. In other words, I believe your data may be lost forever in this unfortunate case. It one off the primary reasons I have been reluctant to use any such software.

Comment: You also might want to try https://superuser.com/questions/221495/recover-data-from-a-corrupt-truecrypt-encrypted-partiton if that may apply; truecrypt does provide a rescue disk although I'm not sure if it will apply in your case.

Comment: Someone else here https://superuser.com/questions/259424/recovering-corrupt-truecrypt-disk had some success with File Scavenger although I cannot attest to it.

Comment: I also recognize this question is 6 years old, so original poster is long gone and so is their data. Maybe will help others.