# TrueCrypt crashed during encryption, files recoverable?

Tags: data-recovery, truecrypt

I was encrypting a ~4.5TB external drive with TrueCrypt and it crashed at roughly 0.04% completion when I attempted to pause it. I've tried a few tools in an attempt to recover my files, however they all give a similar error along the lines of "Unable to determine filesystem type".

I'm assuming since the encryption barely got through any of the drive, a lot of my data should be recoverable. How can I go about recovering this data, preferably for free?

Comment: You can't; recover from a backup

Comment: @Ramhound If it only made it 0.04% through the data, I would expect the majority of the disk to be recoverable assuming it isn't highly fragmented and such. user56172, have you tried PhotoRec? I've used it to much success in the past with failing/dying/corrupted drives (albeit, not partially-encrypted ones).

Comment: @DarthAndroid Currently running PhotoRec and it is successfully recovering files. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Truecrypt provides a rescue disk. You burn it on a CD/DVD and starts the computer from it.

The following seems to apply to you:

If the TrueCrypt Boot Loader screen does not appear after you start your computer (or if Windows does not boot), the TrueCrypt Boot Loader may be damaged.
For more information, see: http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/rescue-disk

This info was taken from another poster. Here is a link to his post just in case.
https://superuser.com/a/221496/565052